# React-boostrap problems with navDropdown

Tags: navbar, react-bootstrap

I'm using react bootstrap components to create navbar. I need to add text and glyphicon to my dropdown item, but if I place it inside this tag or above it's either displayed in dropdown menu or not display at all. How can I put it right inside this button?

```
render () {
return (
  <Nav pullRight>
    <NavDropdown id="nav-dropdown">
      <Glyphicon glyph="glyphicon glyphicon-user">{this.props.username}</Glyphicon>
    </NavDropdown>
  </Nav>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render () {
  return (
    <Nav pullRight>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">
        {this.props.username}
        <Glyphicon glyph="glyphicon glyphicon-user"/>
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
  )
}
```

use {this.props.username} outside the Glyphicon. Do you have link to the original library you are using.

Comment: thanks! this is works, but it's not I actually wanted. I'm using react-bootstrap. here is link: https://react-bootstrap.github.io

Comment: can you clarify where you want the icon to appear. Should it be next to the arrow? besides the arrow? inside opened drop down menu? ...